# Mongoose FindOne method always returning 'null'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make my express app working with MongoDb, using mongoose.

Here is the code (After *edit*):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
/* GET admin page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('admin/admin', {
        title: 'Admin'
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    Users.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err, user);
    });
    // console.log(req.body.username, req.body.password);
    // passport.authenticate('local', {
    //     successRedirect: '/',
    //     failureRedirect: '/admin'
    // });
});
module.exports = router;
```

My problem here is that I can't find user in my collection. I already try to specify a collection name, with multiple string format (Capitalize or not), as you can see and like other post's answer on the same subjet point out.

The findOne() method always pass through the error callback, even if the document is correctly added to the collection.

If someone of you have a idea or something !

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :**

I updated the code for something more logical, after your advise.

In my MongoLab `Users` collection, i have got one document like this :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5641e9a1e4b0af6681f0bef1"
    },
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
```

After `POST` data, "admin" exactly as username, the mongoose query return this :

```
web.1  | admin                // req.body.username
web.1  | Error: null null     // findOne() error callback
```

The mongoDB manipulation is only in `./routes/admin.js` , and `moongose.connection` only happens in `./index.js`. I am not very comfortable with the module concept...

Comment: What does User.find() give you (return all of your saved documents)?

Comment: You seem to be adding the user on every invocation of the application. This makes me think that your case  here is actually a failing test, and not a failing application. Code in nodejs is "asynchronous", which though you seem to get part of the concept, you don't seem to be realizing that `.save()` operation is not necessarily being called before the route becomes available and is likely being called in a "test". Hence, no data. You need to make sure the data is saved "before" you ask to recall it. And you should not be retrieving data in a "POST" request anyway, as it is meant for adding.

Comment: You don't need to specify the name of the mongo collection: `mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)` will automatically create a collection called `users`.

Comment: @Blakes Seven Thanks for your explanation ! I m wondering even if the application adding a user document each time, after 5 or 6 time, findOne() should give me something back isn't it ? Because document with username : "John" existing in the collection.

Comment: The main point I was making was that clearly there is some other interaction other than the code listed here happening ( such as an automated test case ) which would explain why calling a POST method was seeing no data. By the same case, it seems likely that data is being deleted by something else on each run. So there is basically other code here at work that you are not telling us about, that explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run a query you have to create a model first:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String});
var Users = mongoose.model('Users-CollectionName', schema);
```

And then query your database as u like.

```
    Users.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
}, function(err, user) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err, user);
});
```